Type undefined error while compiling Xiaomi kernel
  HDRTEST usr/include/audio/sound/msmcal-hwdep.h
In file included from <built-in>:1:
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:17:2: error: unknown type name 'bool'
        bool classh_bst_override;
        ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:18:2: error: unknown type name 'bool'
        bool classh_algo_enable;
        ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:28:2: error: unknown type name 'bool'
        bool is_present;
        ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:29:2: error: unknown type name 'bool'
        bool irq_pol_inv;
        ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:30:2: error: unknown type name 'bool'
        bool irq_out_en;
        ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:35:2: error: unknown type name 'bool'
        bool sclk_frc;
        ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:36:2: error: unknown type name 'bool'
        bool lrclk_frc;
        ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:37:2: error: unknown type name 'bool'
        bool right_channel;
        ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:38:2: error: unknown type name 'bool'
        bool amp_gain_zc;
        ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:39:2: error: unknown type name 'bool'
        bool dsp_ng_enable;
        ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:40:2: error: unknown type name 'bool'
        bool tuning_has_prefix;
        ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:41:2: error: unknown type name 'bool'
        bool invert_pcm;
        ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:42:2: error: unknown type name 'bool'
        bool hibernate_enable;
        ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:43:2: error: unknown type name 'bool'
        bool fwname_use_revid;
        ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:61:2: error: unknown type name 'bool'
        bool extclk_cfg;
        ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:73:21: error: field has incomplete type 'str
uct work_struct'
        struct work_struct ramp_work;
                           ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:73:9: note: forward declaration of 'struct w
ork_struct'
        struct work_struct ramp_work;
               ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:74:15: error: field has incomplete type 'str
uct mutex'
        struct mutex vol_mutex; /* Protect set volume */
                     ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:74:9: note: forward declaration of 'struct m
utex'
        struct mutex vol_mutex; /* Protect set volume */
               ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:75:2: error: unknown type name 'atomic_t'
        atomic_t manual_ramp; /* boolean */
        ^
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:76:2: error: unknown type name 'atomic_t'
        atomic_t ramp_abort; /* boolean */
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.

kernel source: https://github.com/xiaomi-sm8550/android_kernel_xiaomi_sm8550/tree/lineage-21
modules source: https://github.com/xiaomi-sm8550/android_kernel_xiaomi_sm8550-modules
cs35l41.h is located in android_kernel_xiaomi_sm8550-modules/qcom/opensource/audio-kernel/include/uapi/audio/sound
I tried to add types.h and workqueue.h to cs35l41.h and it gives me this error:
./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h:16:10: fatal error: 'linux/workqueue.h' file
not found
#include <linux/workqueue.h>


The file cs35l41.h has been added 4 days ago: https://github.com/xiaomi-sm8550/android_kernel_xiaomi_sm8550-modules/commit/e8b672257374c555131ccacf9e68a2a26b20467a. Like any other header under uapi/, it shouldn't contain work_struct and mutex types: these types are used only by the kernel. You are better to report the problems to the developers.

@Tsyvarev, their idea AFAICS is to compile modules in the full kernel environment, i.e. it's fine that they have struct mutex or other internal types.

@0andriy: There is nothing wrong in compiling a module in the full kernel environment. But headers under uapi/ are intended to be used not only by the modules, but by the user space code too. For user space types like work_struct has no sense. Note, that the errors are emitted not during normal compilation of the kernel/module objects, but at the HDRTEST step. As far as I can tell from the name of this step, its purpose is to verify the headers.

@Tsyvarev, where did you get anything about UAPI?

@0andriy: The file ./usr/include/audio/sound/cs35l41.h noted in the error message is actually a copy of the file include/uapi/audio/sound/cs35l41.h, as has been found by OP.

@Tsyvarev, right, but it doesn't mean they are going to be used in uAPI. I admit that this is weird and most likely developers of the Android for that phone have no clue what they are doing. Still their buildsystem may be equally broken and allow (in some cases) to build those broken module sources.
